# SwiftUI List with NavigationLink. How to change highlight color on tap?

Tags: list, row, swiftui, highlight, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a List with NavigationLink inside. When I tap on a row, it is highlighted. The color connected to User Interface Style (in info.plist), it can be dark or light. How to change the color of this highlight? I founded some decisions here, with "EpmtyView()" and ".buttonStyle()", but they don't work in my case. With custom button style only the contents of the cell are highlighted (text, for example), but not the cell itself. The problem, I think, connected to "selectionStyle", cause "UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none" remove this highlight.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]

    init() {
         UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.myArray, id: \.self) { text in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                            MyRow(text: text)
                        }
                        .listRowBackground(Color.black)
                    }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            }.background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let standartAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        standartAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = standartAppearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = standartAppearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = standartAppearance
    }
}
```

[image: row highlight]